# C++ scanf was not declared in this scope

Tags: compiler-errors, scanf, stdio

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long int N = 0, product, sum;
    int t; scanf_s("%d", &t);  //// ERROR STARTS AT THIS LINE
    while (t--)
    {
        sum = 0;

        scanf_s("%d", &N);
        N = N / 2;

        product = 1;
        sum = 1; 
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        {
            product = product * i;
            sum += product;
        }

        printf("%d \n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get this **compiling error** when submitting solution to www.codechef.com

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:9:25: error: 'scanf_s' was not declared in this scope
  int t; scanf_s("%d", &t);
```

I have tried compiling with `C++ (gcc-4.3.2)`, `(C++ gcc-4.9.2)` and `C++ 14 (g++4.9.2)`, didn't work.
Why..? I have included `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: `scanf_s` is Microsoft-specific.

Comment: woah thanks! that helps!! :DDD

Answer (score 3):

You can change 
`scanf_s` to `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe help adding

```
#include <cstdio>
```

and use

```
std::sscanf
```

instead of `sscanf`